# Does this variation of Oberwolfach/social-golfer problem have a solution?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Suppose you have tables of various sizes and exactly enough people to fill all their seats.

1. Find necessary and sufficient conditions on the tables such that every person can be seated at the same table as every other exactly once over some number of meals.
2. Develop a general seating strategy for tables that meet the condition.
3. Count the number of such schedules for a viable table arrangement assuming every seat at a table is identical but every person is distinct.

(I believe that the number of meals must be: $\frac{nCr(\text{Total Seats, 2})}{\sum nCr(k_i\text{, 2})}$) where $k_i$ is the number of seats at the i'th table.
Also, there is a sharp lower bound on the number of tables needed : $NumTables \geq k_{max}$ or there must be only one table)

My question from here is if any of these three tasks have been solved?

Comment: I now realize this is more of a variation of the "social golfer problem" .

Comment: Tip: use ```\text{}``` to format text in MathJax. $\text{Total Seats}$ is a bit nicer than $TotalSeats$.